# how to get mouse pointer component in swing application

Tags: java, swing, listener, jbutton

my swing application one panel have 6 button. when cursor goes on the button i want to change default cursor to hand cursor and cursor is exit then it want to change default cursor. Now i am doing this thing using below code.

```
private void btnRegisterReceiptMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                
    btnRegisterReceipt.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
}                                               

private void btnRegisterReceiptMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                               
    btnRegisterReceipt.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
}
```

Now i want to write this code to each and every button.

But I want to write common method to do this one. I already try to use MouseListener do this thing, but I can not get which is the mouse point component.

I don't know it is possible or not. if it is possible please anyone tell me how to do this things.

```
private void changeCursor() {
    addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e ) {
            /*if ( mouse Entered compornent is button ) {
                button.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
            } else {
                button.setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT_CURSOR));
            }*/
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a generic MouseListener (as an annonymouse class):

```
MouseListener ml = new MouseAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        e.getComponent( setCursor(...) );
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        e.getComponent( setCursor(...) );
    }
};
```

Then you can just add the MouseListener to any component you want with:

```
btnRegisterReceipt.addMouseListener( ml );
anotherButton.addMouseListener( ml );
```

You can also make this as a reusable class:

```
public MousePointerListener extends MouseAdapter
{
    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
    {
        e.getComponent( setCursor(...) );
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
    {
        e.getComponent( setCursor(...) );
    }
}
```

Then you use:

```
MouseListener ml = new MousePointerListener();
btnRegisterReceipt.addMouseListener( ml );
anotherButton.addMouseListener( ml );
```

The key point in both examples is that you can get the source of the event from the MouseEvent, which allows you to write generic code. You should look at this approach for all you listeners, instead of letting your IDE generate the listener code.

Comment: +1 - Thanks for the Help. It is work. 
     e.getComponent().setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor‌​.HAND_CURSOR));